# Change theme_color when switching to dark mode

Tags: javascript, manifest.json

I am currently developing a website/web app with a dark mode functionality. The idea is that under certain circumstances (user interaction with a control or time of day), the application palette will update from an off-white color scheme to a dark gray/gray-blue color scheme.

My concern is that the `theme_color` defined in my manifest will not match the dark mode color palette when switched, which will make the dark mode top bar on mobile look a bit odd.

Is there a way to make the `theme_color` change dynamically based on the website's colors? Or, even better, is there a way to specify a condition or programmatically update the `theme_color` when the application changes from one mode to another (i.e. via JS on the client-side)?

On a side note, I am using CSS custom properties in my website, if that can be of use in switching from one color palette to another for the `theme_color`.

Comment: You could have 2 `manifest.json` files, and change which one is linked to. I'm not sure if that'd properly update in the browser, though.

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't think I really have a lot of choices when it comes to picking a manifest file, as it normally loads from a page's `<head>`, so that might not really be an option.

Comment: You _can_ change the file it links to, though. But if the browser would detect that change? Give it a try...

Comment: @Cerbrus doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Ah that’s a bummer

Comment: Hey, wondering if you've since come across any solution as I'm running into the same issue. @AngelosChalaris

Comment: @AlexandreHitchcox No, I have not found a solution. The thing I decided to do is use a darker off-color (highlight with more vibrant color) as the theme color of my app, so that it fits nicely with the dark mode and contrasts the light mode sufficiently without looking weird.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I've been trying a bunch of stuff around and I don't think it's possible currently... ‍♂️

Answer (score 5):

Full credit to @smat-8097 for this, just adding it as an answer because

1. It works, and
2. It was lost in the comments of their sessionStorage answer

Use:

```
document.querySelector('meta[name="theme-color"]').setAttribute('content', '#123456');
```

This can be called to dynamically change the theme color -- just remove any theme_color attributes in manifest.json (background_color is okay to have).

Answer (score 0):

You may use sessionStorage to specify which mode is enabled , and accordingly assign manifest files on window load by using sessionStorage.get .

Comment: That sounds like a plausible solution. Could you provide some sample code?

Comment: This is a basic implementation of the idea , check this out : https://jsbin.com/konatiniwi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The example does not seem to accomplish what I want. I can change colors on the page and CSS, I want the manifest to update according to the CSS, not the other way round.

Comment: Are you like trying to modify the JSON file on change of theme ?

Comment: Yeah, I would like to be able to change the `theme_color` when the theme changes, as I stated in my question.

Comment: What are you using for backend ? It would be easier if you are doing On NodeJS.

Comment: You cannot access a Local file using JavaScript , leave alone modifying it .

Comment: You can easily use the condition to check time and modify JSON on the server itself before serving.

Comment: I am serving my app via Netlify so I have very little to no access as to what is served. Apart from that, doing this on the backend is not at all the solution. The user can and will change from light to dark mode every once in a while manually and when he/she does, I want the browser window top bar to respond to the change.

Comment: But it would be same for all the users , right ? As the dark mode would enable after a certain time for all the users. Hence , if you serve the files accordingly , it would be the solution

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong , Dp you wish to change the color of the browser taskbar ... using <meta name=theme-color ...> ?

Comment: Yeah, `theme-color` in the taskbar could theoretically work, but it does not actually update automatically when the theme changes (meaning that you cannot trigger the browser to repaint its GUI if you just change `theme-color`). Therefore, while this is very close to a solution, it does not work as intended.

Comment: may be you could have a redirect url , like dark.domain.com , so when it's time for dark , you can redirect the user to that url....see if it helps

Comment: That's not the right way to use a subdomain and, even if so, it would divide traffic and cause unnecessary requests and reloads. Definitely not a good option.

Comment: Ohh , best of luck.

Comment: By the way  , did you try this :                            `document.querySelector('meta[name="theme-color"]').setAttribute('content', '#123456'); `